# Is there an alternative to waitForFinished method to check if the process is finished?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qprocess

I am currently trying to create an app with PyQt5 and the GUI keeps on hanging.

There were a couple of backend exe files that needed to be executed in the app using command prompt and I found out about the fact that waitForFinished blocks the entire GUI.

I tried going searching it everywhere but no luck. I just found that most of the related questions had just one answer which was to use signals instead of waitForFinished(-1). I wanted to learn how to use signals but nowhere could I find a tutorial of any sorts that could help me.

The code is:

```
process = QProcess()
cd = "babel.exe"
tem = " "
if not file.endswith("mol"):
    tem = re.sub('\..*', '.mol', file)
    filech = tem
    ar = [file, filech, "-rcpb"]
    process.start(cd, ar)
    process.waitForFinished(-1)
    process.kill
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: The problem for me is that the linked question tells me about finished() method but I don't know how to translate it to python.

Comment: Also, my question is for all the alternatives for the hanging issue and waitForFinished() method

Comment: What about this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148477/using-qprocess-finished-in-python-3-and-pyqt) in python?

Comment: @quamrana You are literally a lifesaver. Thanks