# QProcess not invoking finished?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qprocess

I tried implementing the suggestion from [subprocess Popen blocking PyQt GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613922/subprocess-popen-blocking-pyqt-gui) but it appears that the onFinished function is never getting invoked.

```
class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

[...]

    def Run_PnL_Script(self):
        self.Run_PnL.setEnabled(False)
        self.Run_PnL.setStyleSheet("background-color: #D3D3D3; color: #FFFFFF")
        self.PnL_Status.setText("Running...")
        process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        process.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
        process.startDetached("cmd.exe", ["/c", "K:\Market Risk\Risk App\Batches\RTest.bat"])

    def onFinished(self, exitCode, exitStatus):
        self.PnL_Status.setText("Complete.")
        self.Run_PnL.setEnabled(True)
        self.Run_PnL.setStyleSheet("background-color: #4582EC; color: #FFFFFF")

[...]
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: show RTest.bat...

Comment: @eyllanesc RTest.bat: `"K:\Market Risk\Risk App\R-3.6.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "K:\Market Risk\R\Scripts\Test.R"` Test.R: `Sys.sleep(5)` The `.bat` file runs fine on it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

- When you finish executing a command in cmd.exe does not imply that you close the cmd.exe, so you must close it using the EXIT command at the end of the .bat.

**RTest.bat**

```
:: Another commands
EXIT
```

- Do not use [`startDetached()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-1) since this is a static method that creates an internal QProcess different from the "process" variable, you must use the [`start()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start) method.

```py
# ...
process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
process.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
process.start("cmd.exe", ["/c", "K:\Market Risk\Risk App\Batches\RTest.bat"])
```

Comment: You are a life saver. Works great!